# How to get a location on GPS open street map using android above 5.1

Tags: java, android, gps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using the location manager to find my location, but when I simulate with an api greater than 18, I can not find the location

```
package br.com.josileudorodrigues.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cocoahero.android.geojson.GeoJSON;

import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlDocument;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.location.NominatimPOIProvider;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.location.POI;
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;
import org.osmdroid.events.MapEventsReceiver;
import org.osmdroid.events.MapListener;
import org.osmdroid.events.ScrollEvent;
import org.osmdroid.events.ZoomEvent;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.Projection;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.FolderOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.MapEventsOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PathOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ScaleBarOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.infowindow.InfoWindow;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.infowindow.MarkerInfoWindow;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.GpsMyLocationProvider;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.MyLocationNewOverlay;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MapEventsReceiver, LocationListener {

    private static final int PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA =1 ;
    private MapView osm;
    private MapController mc;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private PathOverlay po;
    private KmlDocument kmlDocument;


    ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        osm = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapaId);
        osm.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        osm.setUseDataConnection(true);
        osm.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        osm.setClickable(true);
        osm.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String[] permissoes = {Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissoes, PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA);
            }
        }

        osm.setMapListener(new MapListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                Log.i("Script()", "onScroll ()");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {
                Log.i("Script()", "onZoom ()");
                return false;
            }
        });


        //onde mostra a imagem do mapa
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));

        mc = (MapController) osm.getController();
        mc.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(-5.1251, -38.3640);
        mc.animateTo(center);
        addMarker(center);
// here is where the permissions are

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 

        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            // .
            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        MapEventsOverlay mapEventsOverlay = new MapEventsOverlay(this, this);
        osm.getOverlays().add(0, mapEventsOverlay);

        // Aqui adiciona a escala do mapa
        ScaleBarOverlay scaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(osm);
        osm.getOverlays().add(scaleBarOverlay);

        kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
    //    kmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(geoJsonString);


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA: {
                // Se a solicitação de permissão foi cancelada o array vem vazio.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permissão cedida, recria a activity para carregar o mapa, só será executado uma vez
                    this.recreate();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void addMarker(final GeoPoint center) {
        final Marker marker = new Marker(osm);
        marker.setPosition(center);
        marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        marker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mapa));
        marker.setDraggable(true);

        marker.setTitle("DADOS");
        marker.setSnippet(center.getLatitude()+ "," + center.getLongitude());
        marker.setSubDescription("subDescription Marker");

        marker.setInfoWindow(new CustomMarkerInfoWindow(osm));
        marker.setInfoWindowAnchor(marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, marker.ANCHOR_TOP);

        marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker m, MapView mapView) {
                Log.i("Script","onMarkerClick");
                m.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });

        marker.setOnMarkerDragListener(new Marker.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                Log.i("Script", "onMarkerDragStart()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                Log.i("Script", "onMarkerDragEnd()");

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                Log.i("Script", "onMarkerDrag()");
            }
        });

        //osm.getOverlays().clear();
        osm.getOverlays().add(new MapOverlay(this));
        osm.getOverlays().add(marker);
        osm.invalidate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mc.animateTo(center);
        addMarker(center);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
        }
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
        public MapOverlay(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas c, MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent me, MapView mv) {
            Projection p = osm.getProjection();
            GeoPoint gp = (GeoPoint) p.fromPixels((int) me.getX(), (int) me.getY());
            addMarker(gp);
            return (true);
        }
    }

    // Aqui quando eu pressionar em uma determinada parte do mapa ele
    // irá  mostrar as minhas cordenadas
    @Override
    public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Coordenadas:\nLatitude: ("+p.getLatitude() +"\nLongitude: " +
                ""+p.getLongitude()+")" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        InfoWindow.closeAllInfoWindowsOn(osm); //Clicando em qualquer canto da tela, fecha o infowindow
        return (true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPressHelper(GeoPoint p) {
        return false;
    }

    // InfoWindow
    public class CustomMarkerInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {

        public CustomMarkerInfoWindow(MapView mapView) {
            super(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble,mapView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Object item){

            Marker m = (Marker) item;

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_image);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_moreinfo);

            TextView snippet = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_title);
            snippet.setText(m.getTitle());

            TextView coordenada = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id. coordenadas);
            coordenada.setText(m.getSnippet());

            Button bt = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_buttom);
            bt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Salvo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1uTG.png)

How would you fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to request GPS permissions from the user on APIs > 21 (i think)
2. On every gps update, roughly once a second, you are adding a new marker to the map. You'll eventually run out of memory. Consider just updating the marker's location.
3. See this https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library#how-to-add-the-my-location-overlay that overlay is a bit easier to use that rolling your own solution, but whatever. Here's a working example of using it https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/location/SampleMyLocationWithClick.java (code is below)
4. Not all emulators do GPS. Sometimes you have to poke around in the menus to stimulate it. Try to reproduce on hardware. Genymotion works pretty well

Code snippet

```
 final MyLocationOverlayWithClick overlay = new    MyLocationOverlayWithClick(mMapView);
  overlay.enableFollowLocation();
  overlay.enableMyLocation();
  mMapView.getOverlayManager().add(overlay);
```

Finally you can run the sample app from here, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.osmdroid or you can get the APK on github. If that doesn't work in your emulator, then the emulator is broken or doesn't support gps

Comment: I did not get it yet, For me to use map overlay, do I need to use that proxy?

Comment: up to the version of android 4.1, it works fine, but above it no longer shows the location